# How to Inject service in spec file Angular Testing (Jasmin/karma)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, karma-jasmine

I am new to write `Angular` unit test case. I am injecting one service in my controller file(.ts). How Will I inject service file in spec file.

Here is the code:

**app.component.ts**

```
getSortData() {
    this.sortService.sortNumberData(this.data, 'name', 'asce');
}
```

**sort.service.ts**

```
sortNumberData(data, rendererKey, type) {
    // data.sort((elem1, elem2) => {
    //   //if number is undefined, then assigning `MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` to to move it to the last in order. 
    //   if (elem1[rendererKey] == undefined) elem1[rendererKey] = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER;
    //   if (!elem2[rendererKey] == undefined) elem2[rendererKey] = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER;
    //   return Number(elem1[rendererKey]) - Number(elem2[rendererKey]);
    // });
    // if (type == "desc") {
    //   return data.reverse();
    // }
    // return data;   
    if (!Array.isArray(rendererKey)) {
        data.sort((elem1, elem2) => {
            if (elem1[rendererKey] == undefined && elem2[rendererKey] == undefined) {
                return 0;
            } else if (elem1[rendererKey] == undefined) {
                return 1;
            } else if (elem2[rendererKey] == undefined) {
                return -1;
            } else {
                return elem1[rendererKey] - elem2[rendererKey];
            }
        });
        // if the type of rendererKey is array, then use array elements as keys hierarchally.
        // This is used when compare element is not direct property of each element of data array.
    } else if (Array.isArray(rendererKey)) {
        data.sort((elem1, elem2) => {
            let temp1 = elem1, temp2 = elem2;
            rendererKey.map((e) => { temp1 = temp1[e], temp2 = temp2[e] });
            console.log(temp1, temp2);
            if (temp1 == undefined && temp2 == undefined) {
                return Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER - Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER
            } else if (temp1 == undefined) {
                return Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER - temp2;
            } else if (temp2 == undefined) {
                return temp1 - Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER;
            } else {
                return temp1 - temp2;
            };
        })

    }
    if (type == "desc") {
        return data.reverse();
    }
    return data;
}
```

We don't know. How to inject this service in spec file. Can anyone help us?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking how to unit test the component (app.component.spec.ts), or how to unit test the service (sort.service.spec.ts)?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The one you are trying to achieve is actually Integration testing because you are trying to test two units ( `AppComponent` and `SortService`) both collectively.

Since you are talking about unit testing then i think you want to test `AppComponent` class. Which means any injectable dependency which is used in `AppComponent` need to be mocked. In your case it is the `SortService` class. There are two ways to do it.

> Approach 1 : Using Mock class for `SortService`.
>
> `app.component.spec.ts`

```
// Mock the SortService class, its method and return it with mock data
class MockSortService extends SortService{
                getSortData(data, rendererKey, type) {
                    return [someRandomArray];
                }
}

beforeEach(async( () => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            providers: [                   
                // Use the power of Angular DI with following provider. This will replace SortService with MockSortService in injector
                { provide: SortService, useClass: MockSortService },
            ]
    });
));
```

> Approach 2 : Using Spy object.
>
> app.component.spec.ts

```
beforeEach(async( () => {
        // Create jasmine spy object 
        sortServiceSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('SortService', 'sortNumberData');
        // Provide the dummy/mock data to sortNumberData method.
        sortServiceSpy.sortNumberData.returnValue([someRandomArray]);
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
                providers: [                   
                    { provide: SortService, useValue: sortServiceSpy},
                ]
        });
    ));
```

I liked the approach 2. It is small and elegant. But you can use any of the two approaches.

Hope this will help !

Comment: I was trying to pass `spy` as `useClass` but thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 6):

For inject a service into spec file, you have to add TestBed configuration and register your service in provider array same as module ts file.

Example :-

```
describe('description of test case', () => { 
    
   const sortService;


   beforeEach(async( () => {
     TestBed.configureTestingModule({
         declarations: [],    
         providers: [SortService]
      }).compileComponents();
   }));

   beforeEach( () => {
       sortService = TestBed.get(SortService);
   });
```

Answer (score 5):

This answer assumes you want to unit test the component.

If you use the Angular TestBed for testing your components, it can handle doing the service injection for you by specifying it in the providers array.  Assuming you want to test the component (and just mock the service), I would do something like this:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { SortService } from '../services/sort.service';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

describe('app component', () => {
    let component: AppComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;
    let spySortService = jasmine.createSpyObj({ sortNumberData: null });

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [/* add all needed imports for AppComponent */],
            declarations: [ AppComponent ],
            providers: [
                { provide: SortService, useValue: spySortService }
            ]
        });
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
  }));

    it('should create', () => {
        expect(fixture).toBeTruthy();
    });
    it('getSortData() should call SortService sortNumberData() method', () => {
        fixture.detectChanges();
        component.getSortData();
        expect(spySortService.sortNumberData.toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```